# Is it possible to specify multiple prefixes and suffixes to S3 Lambda Event trigger for object uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that needs to be invoked when an object is uploaded to a bucket. It needs to be invoked only if the object is uploaded with `prefixA/` or `prefixB/`.
But, I can see that it only supports a single prefix and a single suffix:
[image]

Is it possible to specify multiple prefixes and suffixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out that I can create 2 separate triggers, each with their own prefixes, i.e `prefixA` and `prefixB`. So, I can specify as many prefixes as I want, with separate triggers.